# Video card driver beginner nightmare

Tags: drivers, ati, reset

First of all I'm a beginner on ubuntu so please forgive me if I lack any basic knowledge.

Here's my issue : yesterday I installed ubuntu and somehow I managed to kind of ruin my video card drivers.

I was doing fine until today when I reboot the resolution of my screen is detected wrongly. I go to the driver list and all option are greyed out, leaving me with " continue using manually installed drivers ". I google the issue and end up with a bunch of commands that eventually allowed me to choose again between the drivers.

Problem is it didn't fix anything. So I still have a wrong resolution ( that is the only option in the "displays" setting ) and it seems the video card ain't really used because of the very laggy desktop navigation.

What I'm asking is some sort of commands that I could run to basically reset the graphical driver to a default.

I realise I'm this position because I pasted some random commands without really understanding what I was doing, so please bear with me and try and explain to me what the command does.

Also I assume you'll need more informations so please ask but explain to me how to get those informations.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please post those commands you did. Please be specific, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It appears that somehow my motherboard decided not to recognize my graphic card anymore during the night. Earlier I unplugged it and rubbed it with hope and it did recognize it ( no kidding xD ). So I took no chance and did a full ubuntu reinstall. I guess this topic can be closed, thanks mchid =)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can install ati proprietary graphics drivers through `apt-get`. First, perform all system updates and upgrades before you begin:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

reboot

Then, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

Alternatively, and to set back to default, you should be able to open 
"additional drivers" in your system settings. Wait a few moments for the drivers to be detected. Then, it should list the available, in use, and recommended proprietary and opensource drivers available.

The default drivers are the opensource drivers.

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)